# Autocalculation of a field value in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

There is a Cassandra table as follows.

```
  Student(eName text, eId int PRIMARY KEY, m1 int, m2 int, average float)
```

How can the average value be autocalculated on inserting values for other fields of the row?
That is, we need to insert only eName, eId, m1 and m2; average has to be autocalculated and entered in the tuple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra has [built-in CQL aggregate functions](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/trunk/cassandra/cql/functions.html#aggregate-functions) such as `AVG()` which computes the average of all values returned by a query, that is, the aggregation takes place at read time (as opposed to write time).

You can also write your own user-defined aggregates (UDAs).

It is possible to implement your own [CQL `TRIGGER`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/trunk/cassandra/cql/triggers.html) which executes Java code when data is written to a table but it has been considered as experimental for a long time and I don't recommend using it.

The general recommendation is to perform the aggregation within your application prior to writing the data to the table. Cheers!